# Spring container start error while using dynamo db from aws sdk 2

Tags: spring, amazon-dynamodb

I am getting a Linkage error while starting my spring container.

```
Error creating bean with name 'dynamoclub' defined in BeanDefinition defined in 
file [C:\VF\project\dynamo\DynamoClub.class]: 
Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is 
org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException: Unexpected AOP exception; nested 
exception is java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: loader 'app' wants to 
load interface software.amazon.awssdk.services.dynamodb.DynamoDbAsyncClient. A different 
interface with the same name was previously loaded by 
org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.classloader.RestartClassLoader @50ec6ac4. 
(software.amazon.awssdk.services.dynamodb.DynamoDbAsyncClient is in unnamed module of 
loader org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.classloader.RestartClassLoader 
@50ec6ac4, parent loader 'app')
```

What is the reason for this error ? Is it the problem with the sdk ?